# Message sending in tinder api returns 500 error

Tags: php, api, tinder

I was working with tinder api. I would like to send messages to all matches in tinder accounts via tinder api. But I am getting getting http_code=500 error every time I wish to send the message to the matches. I also tried to update the bio and bio gets updated successfully but could not split the bio in different line feeds by passing \u000A in place of full stop. Does tinder support unicode?

My code snippet in php is as follows:

```
$data = callCurl("httxx://api.gotinder.com/user/recs", 'GET', $headers);
//print_r($data);

if (!empty($data['results']))
$profiles = $data['results'];
else
return("\nNo more recommendations\n");

foreach($profiles as $profile)
{
unset($profile['photos']);
//echo $profile["_id"];

$x=$x+1;


sleep(1);
$match = callCurl("httxx://api.gotinder.com/like/" . $profile["_id"], "GET", $headers);
//print_r($match);

$match = (bool)$match['match'];


if($match)
{
echo "\nMATCHED!!!!!!!!!!!\n";
$data_m_ = array("message"=> $message,
);

$msgres=callCurl("https://api.gotinder.com/user/matches/" . $profile["_id"], "POST", $headers, $data_m);
if($msgres['http_code']!=200)
echo "Message not sent";  // $msgres['http_code'] returns 500

}

echo ".";
if($x==100)
{
mysql_query("update tinder_accounts set account_status=1 where id='$blog_id_1'");
return("\n100 LIKES EXCEEDED.\n");
}
}
```

Kindly help on this issue for which I will be ever grateful to one who helps me. Thanks Krish

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see if you send the auth tokens correctly but it seems you do not.
The headers from logging in to sending a message are different.
You need to send the x-auth headers as well on sending a message. Rest looks fine.